# Set a data to a specific name with spring & mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query

My json data

```
[{"cameraid":"000000001","timestamp":"2016-06-17 23:08","filename":"7e3800fbd0557c683874ed2f41ed7057"},

 {"cameraid":"000000002","timestamp":"2016-06-17 23:08","filename":"b260cc730da88a6af4e5038d6e1e32db"}]
```

How can i have `cameraid` to link to a specific name?

Like example my `cameraid "000000001"` to be call as `bedok`.

Anybody got any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Do you have a finite set of names or every unique id should be given an unique name? Also, where are these unique name coming from? It is not clear from the above post on how you have determined bedok?

Comment: @notionquest the name of the bedok is just an example.

Comment: @notionquest but you got the idea on what i doing? i stuck with this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to add a `name` field for specific `cameraid`,

Try following query:-

```
db.collname.update({"cameraid":"000000001"},{$set : {name : 'bedok'}});
```

**EDIT:-**

The above query will update only one record which matches the query `{"cameraid":"000000001"}`.

Add `multi:true` to the query, to multiple records.

```
 db.collname.update({"cameraid":"000000001"},{$set : {name : 'bedok'}},{multi : true});
```

Now it will update all the records that matches the query `{"cameraid":"000000001"}`.

Comment: I tried this code but why only update one cameraid for "000000001" as i got 3 of the same cameraid.

Comment: You have to do multi true, if there are multiple records. The query I gave is based on your db structure shown. Will update the answer.

Comment: Updated the answer. You can try now.

Answer (score 1):

Create another collection with names(lets call it db_name) and link the cameraid to the _id of db_name collection. This way you can fetch the names using cameraid. This is more like primary key and foreign key concept in relational database(RDBMS).

More on this with code here: [Primary Key and Foreign Key Concept in MongoDB](http://technotip.com/3000/relationship-between-collections-tables-mongodb/)

Comment: Is it possible if I create one more data on my current collection. And whenever I want to store "000000001" into the database and it will store bedok01 into the database. If I store different data like "000000002" into the database and it will store bedok02. You understand?